# Devise destroying user - uninitialized constant User::Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Hey I'm trying to destroy a user, who was created with devise.

Here are my files:

users_controller.rb

```
before_action :find_user
def destroy
    @user.destroy
    if @user.destroy
        redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User destroyed"
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
```

view:

```
= link_to "delete", admin_destroy_user_path(u), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"}
```

But I get following error message:

```
NameError in UsersController#destroy
uninitialized constant User::Profile
```

Comment: show the part of the controller, where you're using reference to `Profile` or `User::Profile`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
before_action :find_user
def destroy
    if @user.destroy  # in this place you will destroy your user
        redirect_to admin_users_path, notice: "User destroyed"
    end
end
```